# is thare a way to convert a int into binary and put it into a array

Tags: c, binary

I am making a program for my arduino that needs to access a eeprom but I need to find a way to send it a address, I have a int I would like to convert into binary and send to the eeprom but I need to split it into a array so I can send the data to the eeprom.

I cant think of any way to do this and I have asked some people for help but they couldn't figure out how to ether.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to binary"?  If it's in an `int` variable, then it's already in binary.  Do you want to print it out in human-readable binary characters (`'0'` and `'1'`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void int_to_bin_array(unsigned int in, int count, int* out)
{
    unsigned int mask = 1U << (count-1);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        out[i] = (in & mask) ? 1 : 0;
        in <<= 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int binary_array[8];
    const int bin_size = 8;
    int decimal = 15;

    int_to_bin_array(decimal, bin_size, binary_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory addresses are hexadecimal values, not binary. You don't need to do this here.

You need to correctly understand memory interfacing with your MCU (Arduino in this case) along with embedded systems concepts and pointers in C.

You can specify address values in hexadecimal values directly (uint_t addr = (uint_t *) 0x1234ABCD) and the compiler will automatically convert it to respective binary, during compilation.

Comment: i need to use binary because im using a EEPROM and its address pins are connected to it